# How to do a lookup based on table's row value in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two tables:
Table A:

```
   state  value
0     A     100
```

Table B:

```
   state  100  200
0      A    1    4
1      B    2    5
2      C    3    6
```

I want to create a new field for Table A called "Factor" that returns the respective value from Table B:

```
   state  value  factor
0     A     100       1
```

How would I do this in Python/Pandas?

In Excel, I would do: INDEX('Table B'!B2:C4, MATCH('Table A'!A2, 'Table B'!A:A, 0), MATCH('Table A'!B2, 'Table B'!B1:C1, 0))

Comment: So you only want to select column `100` from Table B? Look at `pd.merge`

Answer (score 1):

1. Pivot `dfA` from wide to long format using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).  Ensure the column names get converted to a numeric type.
2. [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the longform data to `dfA`

```
melted = dfB.melt(id_vars=['state'], var_name='value', value_name='factor')
melted['value'] = melted['value'].astype(int)
dfA = dfA.merge(melted, on=['state', 'value'])
```

Result:

```
  state  value  factor
0     A    100       1
```

This maybe feels like overkill for this example, but could be helpful for larger lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `loc` for this. Please try the following example:

Assuming Table A (dfA) and Table B (dfB) are both pandas dataframes:

```
>>> A = {
    'state' : ['A'],
    'value' : [100],
}

>>> B = {
    'state' : ['A','B','C'],
    '100' : [1,2,3],
    '200' : [4,5,6]
}

>>> dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
>>> dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
```

which gives you your tables as pandas dataframes

```
>>> dfA
state   value
0   A   100

>>> dfB
state   100 200
0   A   1   4
1   B   2   5
2   C   3   6
```

Then we search a specific column in the dataframe for a specific value and return the value of a different column from that same row.

```
extracted_value = list(dfB.loc[dfB['state'] == 'A', '100'])[0]
```

We create a column and set that value for that column `dfA['factor'] = extracted_value`

and we now have that extracted value in the appropriate column

```
>>> dfA
state   value   factor
0   A   100      1
```

Now I'm sure you want to do this in a loop to address a particular list of values and I hope this helps you start. Additionally, using `dfA['factor'] = extracted_value` is going to set every value in that column to *extracted_value* and you might want to have different values per row. To accomplish that you're going to want to use .loc again to add values based on the row index.